# external hard disk not show

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I bought new Dell Inspiron laptop and took apart my old HP probook laptop to get its hard disk and use as an external hard disk for my new laptop. The hard disk already has Windows 8 installed and is divided into 4 partitions: c, d, e, and f. C is the system volume.

The problem is that I cannot see it or access it on my new computer as I am using USB linkage. Also in Disk Management, the icon that refers to the external hard drive has a red arrow, and the field is not active.

The drive contains all my important files. How can I access it from my new computer? Please help.

Comment: Exactly which USB adapter did you use, and how it is attached to the drive?  Is the drive powering up at all?  How does it appear in the Device Manager?  Does the drive work (via USB) any differently when plugged into another computer?

Comment: in the device manager its usb storage device and not work via usb on other computers .. usb adapter name :NESO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible to access the drive through windows operating system directly ,but using Ubuntu for example. is a good solution and that what I had tried and work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach problem from a different angle, put your hard drive back to your old laptop. Boot-up LiveCD e.g. ubuntu linux from usb or CD. You'll have access to your disk and then copy what's important to other media. Or if your laptop still work with original OS copy content from there. Much easier. Sometimes usb adapters don't work well I fried my HDD with one of those.

Comment: if did so then why need live cd.. old laptop will boot up  normally.. isn't it ? .. but I need to this from the new laptop because  I don't have the old laptop right now

Comment: in that case you need to buy a good USB adapter, those from ebay won't work.